# JQuery: Append new element if existing element id doesn't match

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two checkboxes with ids.

**HTML**

```
<div class="controls">
  <label class="checkbox" name="Blood Oxygen">Blood Oxygen
    <input type="checkbox" value="Blood Oxygen" name="1" id="4" checked="checked">
  </label>

  <label class="checkbox" name="Blood Pressure">Blood Pressure
    <input type="checkbox" value="Blood Pressure" name="1" id="6" checked="checked">  </label>
</div>
```

I need to append more checkboxes dynamically. But while adding I've to check if checkboxes with simillar ID exist. I've to ignore the one with similar ids but append others.

Here is my Data source:

```
[{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Respiratory & COPD",
  "slug": "respiratory_and_copd",
  "tests": [{
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Blood Oxygen"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Blood Pressure"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Peak Flow"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Respiratory Timer"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Here is how I'm trying to compare:

```
$.each(data[0].tests, function(key, val) {
  $(".controls input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
    var $checked_test_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($checked_test_id !== val.id) {
      var $control = $('.controls')
      $($control)
        .append('<label class="checkbox" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '">' +
          '<input type="checkbox" value="' + val.name + '" id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</label>');
    }
  })
});
```

This is causing a weird result. I think I'm not thinking straight. How can I append the checkboxes which do not already exist? `Peak Flow` & `Respiratory Timer`

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1b3htqn5/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not exactly sure what you were going for with your code block, heres the simple solution

```
$.each(data[0].tests, function(key, val) {
    var find = $('#' + val.id).length;
    if (find === 0) {
        $('.controls').append('<label class="checkbox" id="' + val.id + '" name="' + val.name + '">' +
            '<input type="checkbox" value="' + val.name + '" id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</label>');
    }
});
```

Loop over all the tests, see if `#<id>` does not exist (length === 0) then if it does not exist, append it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascripts .map() functionn to map over the array and compare values. If there is no match in the array: add your checkbox =)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map